# PHP and JS help: function doesn't accept arguments pasted with echo

Tags: javascript, php

Here's a long code row I'm using to paste HTML via PHP:

```
echo "<h2 style=\"color: white!important; background: black!important; border: 4px black solid!important;\">", $p_name, "<span id=\"portfolio-", $p_id, "\" onclick=\"expandToggle(this);\" style=\"float: right; padding-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;\">+</span>", "<span onmouseover=\"getNotify(this, true)\" onmouseout=\"getNotify(this, false)\" onclick=\"window.open(",$p_get,")\" style=\"float: right; cursor: pointer; padding-right: 15px;\">⬇</span></h2>";
```

$p_get is an URL, window.open(), well, opens a window. However this is what happens if I try to use that:
[image: nothing to see here]

and a JS error in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be new line (`\n`) character around the url.

```
echo "<h2 style=\"color: white!important; background: black!important; border: 4px black solid!important;\">",
 $p_name, "<span id=\"portfolio-", $p_id, "\" onclick=\"expandToggle(this);\" style=\"float: right; padding-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;\">+</span>",
 "<span onmouseover=\"getNotify(this, true)\" onmouseout=\"getNotify(this, false)\" onclick=\"window.open('",str_ireplace("\n", "", $p_get),"')\" style=\"float: right; cursor: pointer; padding-right: 15px;\">⬇</span></h2>";
```

The changed part is:

```
window.open('",str_ireplace("\n", "", $p_get),"')
```

Update:
Since your code can be difficult to read hence difficult to understand here is a better formatted solution.

```
printf(
    '<h2 style="color: white!important; background: black!important; border: 4px black solid!important;">
        %s
        <span id="portfolio-%d" onclick="expandToggle(this);" style="float: right; padding-right: 10px; cursor: pointer;">+</span>
        <span onmouseover="getNotify(this, true)" onmouseout="getNotify(this, false)" onclick="window.open(\'%s\')" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; padding-right: 15px;">⬇</span>
    </h2>',
     $p_name, $p_id, str_replace("\n", "", $p_get)
);
```

Comment: Oh, an error on my side. I'm using a text file to get info from, then looping an array and pasting right into the website. I used explode() php function to divide item parts and their descriptions, and there are nl's. Yep. Thanks!

Comment: Use `PHP_EOL` rather than  "\n"

Comment: @LexLaiden Cheers then.

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be enclosed in quotes, too? As far as I can tell, it's not. That can't be right.

Comment: @Davor it is. Check inside html part.